# using gulp-cached with gulp-sass-ruby

Tags: sass, gulp, gulp-sass

how do I use gulp-cached in latest gulp-sass-ruby, here's my source.

```
g.task('style', function(){
    return sass('../scss/header.scss', {style:'compressed', sourcemap: true})
    .on('error', notify.onError(function (error){
        return "Error: " + error.message;
    }))
    .pipe(cache('cached'))
    // For file sourcemaps
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.', {
        includeContent: false,
        sourceRoot: 'source'
    }))
    .pipe(g.dest('../css'))
    .pipe(notify('scss converted to css and compressed <%= file.relative %>'));
```

});